# Não consigo capturar um valor específico do json

Tags: json, react

Estou tendo o seguinte problema com meu código, que quando eu chamo um campo do meu json ele mostra todas as listas com todos os dados.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/historico',{
            method:'GET',
            headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application-json'
            },
        })
        .then((resp)=>resp.json())
        .then((msg)=>{console.log(msg)})
        .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
    },[])
```

onde o resultado obtido é igual há:

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {nome: 'Caldas Novas', data: '13/08/2022', hora: '00:13:07', id: 1}
1: {nome: 'Caldas Novas', data: '13/08/2022', hora: '00:13:43', id: 2}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Mas quando peço um valor específico dentro desse campo tipo o nome ele se torna indefinido

```js
 useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/historico',{
            method:'GET',
            headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application-json'
            },
        })
        .then((resp)=>resp.json())
        .then((msg)=>{console.log(msg.nome)})
        .catch((err)=>console.log(err))
    },[])
```

O resultado undefined

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

A parte chamada no meu Json está assim:

```js
"historico": [
    {
      "nome": "Caldas Novas",
      "data": "13/08/2022",
      "hora": "00:13:07",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "nome": "Caldas Novas",
      "data": "13/08/2022",
      "hora": "00:13:43",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
```

Comment: o seu json retornar um `array` de objetos e quando você coloca `msg.nome` isso não existe, porque `msg` é um `array`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problema é que esse historico é uma lista, `msg.nome` não existe. Apenas olhando o seu código, não da pra saber se a chamada da API retorna um objeto
`historico` que é uma lista, ou se retorna uma lista sozinha. Estou mostrando pra você duas formas, em que uma delas funciona, dependendo da chamada da API

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const historico = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/historico').then(res => res.json())
  historico.forEach(h => {
    console.log({ h });
  });
}, [])
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const data = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/historico').then(res => res.json())
  data.historico.forEach(h => {
    console.log({ h });
  });
}, [])
```

E no seu caso, não precisa declarar o `method:'GET'` porque é o padrão. Não precisa também do `headers:{'Content-Type':'application-json'}`, porque você não esta fazendo uma alteração no banco, só uma consulta (GET).